# Link 2 Arrary Random with each other

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

I am creating a 'Tips' section which changes on refresh. I had only text earlier but now there is an image associate with each tip.

I am randomising both arrays which is wrong. How do I link them?

It should be 'Tip 1' => '1.jpg', 'Tip 2' => '2.jpg', 'Tip 3' => '3.jpg'

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
<?php
    function array_random($arr, $num = 1) {
            shuffle($arr);

            $r = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            $r[] = $arr[$i];
        }
         return $num == 1 ? $r[0] : $r;
    }

    $a = array(
        "Tip 1", 
        "Tip 2", 
        "Tip 3");

    $img = array(
        "1.jpg", 
        "2.jpg", 
        "3.jpg");
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, join them in one array

```
$tips = array();
$tips[] = array("Tip" => "Tip text 1", "Image" => "Tip Image 1");
$tips[] = array("Tip" => "Tip text 2", "Image" => "Tip Image 2");
shuffle($tips);
echo $tips[0]['Tip']; // tip text
echo $tips[0]['Image']; // tip image
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, but as I want to echo Random tips, I use below code.  <?php echo array_random($a); ?>

Comment: Its works great when I changed shuffle($array); to shuffle($tips); Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$new = array_combine($a,$img);    
shuffle($a);

echo $tip = $a[0];
echo $image = $new[$a[0]];
```